Bulk add multiple videos at once to playlist using YouTube v3 api
I am trying to write a script to add every video from a list to a youtube playlist, currently my project works but I hit the quota limit very fast.
The free tier of my GCP project allows 10,000 values per day

With playlistitems.update costing 50 units
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost
Which means I can only make 200 playlist insert requests per day, and I'm running into that limit.
Is there any way to insert multiple videos into a playlist using a single request? Currently my code does the following:
    while (retries < MAX_RETRIES) {
        try {
            await youtube.playlistItems.insert({
                part: 'snippet',
                requestBody: {
                    snippet: {
                        playlistId: playlistId,
                        resourceId: {
                            kind: 'youtube#video',
                            videoId: videoId
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            console.log(`Added video ${videoId} to playlist.`);
            return; // Success, exit function

Which only inserts one video id at a time, is it possible to insert multiple at once?

My Stack Overflow answer 71970181 solves to some extent this issue.

interesting, thanks for posting. looks like a good solution for using curl requests, I can try to auth that way
